# Как лучше использовать конструкторы анонимных функий?

Tags: javascript

Есть примерно такой код:

```
var request = new function(){
  var 
    jsonAjaxResult, 
    countOfDownloadingArts;

  function downloadArts(){
   return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     // Код для загрузки картинок
   });
  }

  function downloadJSON(){
    return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Код для загрузки json-а
    });
  }

 this.getNewArts = (numberOfShowingArts = 20) => {
   // Обработчик очереди возвращающихся промисов для загрузки 
   // заданного количества картинок (формальный параметр)
 }
}
```

В нем я использую методы таким образом:

```
request.getNewArts(40);
```

Весьма удобно.
Но когда я пишу такого рода конструкцию, то `jsLint` ругается такой ошибкой:

```
Weird construction. Is 'new' necessary?
```

Ну вот и интересуюсь, почему я не могу в качестве конструктора использовать анонимную функцию? Как я понимаю, это просто некрасиво с точки зрения логики, но мне нужен действительно один экземпляр этого функционала.
Как тогда быть? Забить на ошибку или можно как-нибудь переписать код?
Честно говоря, хотелось бы, чтобы было так:

```
function request(){
  // функции и переменные
}
// И использовать вот так:
request.getNewArts(40);
```

Но увы, в js так нельзя, как я понимаю.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54859/discussion-on-question-by-vostoksisters-----).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Оператор `new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) устанавливает `this` внутри функции на новый созданный объект. Таким образом, если `this` не используется внутри функции, это может служить сигналом тому, что и `new` тут может быть не нужен.

Судя по коду в вопросе: в создаваемый объект добавляется метод *getNewArts*, следовательно использование `new` вполне оправдано.

С другой стороны, так как создать еще несколько объектов этого типа будет не совсем тривиально, вызов конструктора можно заменить обычным вызовом функции, возвращающей объект:

```
var request = function(){
  var 
    jsonAjaxResult, 
    countOfDownloadingArts;

  function downloadArts(){
   return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     // Код для загрузки картинок
   });
  }

  function downloadJSON(){
    return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Код для загрузки json-а
    });
  }

  return {
    getNewArts : (numberOfShowingArts = 20) => {
      // Обработчик очереди возвращающихся промисов для загрузки 
      // заданного количества картинок (формальный параметр)
    }
  }
}();
```

В этом случае оператор `new` не нужен.